# Summary table by group in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe:

```
 df <- data.frame(group = c("group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group3"), factor = paste("factor", 1:6, sep=""), vol = seq(from = 0.02, length.out = 6, by = 0.02))
```

The first column defines a top-level group for each factor in the second column. The third column is the value of standard deviation for each factor.

I would like to generate a summary table with the groups only, and the standard deviation for each group defined as:

- If group1 contrains factors f1 and f2, and vol(f1) and vol(f2) are the standard deviations for factors f1 and f2 respectively, then the standard deviation of group1 is:

  `std(group1) = sqrt[vol(f1)^2 + vol(f2)^2]`

Is there any easy way of creating the summary table, where `vol` of each group is computed using this custom function?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I propose a solution using `ddply` function:

```
# require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(group), summarize, std = sqrt(sum(vol^2)))

#    group        std
# 1 group1 0.04472136
# 2 group2 0.14142136
# 3 group3 0.12000000
```

Comment: @Mariam, thank you for accepting my answer. To give you more perspective, I realised that the `plyr` is related to `dplyr` package, which was proposed by @andyteucher. The latter may perform better in larger data frames ([reference](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/01/17/introducing-dplyr/)).

Answer (score 5):

A base solution for good measure.

```
by(df,df$group,function(x) sqrt(sum(x$vol^2)))
```

If you need it to look prettier:

```
as.table(df,df$group,function(x) sqrt(sum(x$vol^2))))

df$group
    group1     group2     group3 
0.04472136 0.14142136 0.12000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the amazing new `dplyr` package, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
require(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(group = c("group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group3"), 
                 factor = paste("factor", 1:6, sep=""), 
                 vol = seq(from = 0.02, length.out = 6, by = 0.02))

df %.% group_by(group) %.% summarise(grp_std=sqrt(sum(vol^2)))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

#    group    std_dev
# 1 group1 0.04472136
# 2 group2 0.14142136
# 3 group3 0.12000000
```

The chaining syntax using `%.%` takes a bit of getting used to, but it becomes very intuitive.  Alternative syntax:

```
df_grouped <- group_by(df, group)

summarise(df_grouped, grp_std=sqrt(sum(vol^2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend `aggregate()` from the basic package `stats`, though you have to define a new function first.

```
ss<-function(x){sqrt(sum(x^2))}
aggregate(vol~group,data=df,FUN=ss)
```